# add Django leaflet location picker on DRF creation form

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, leaflet, geodjango

I'm using leaflet in my admin page easily by this code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin
from location.models import Location

admin.site.register(Location, LeafletGeoAdmin)
```

and I have location picker in my admin page like this:
[image]
I need this form in my DRF form. How to change the default template and add leaflet to the location field?

Here are some of my codes:

`models.py`

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from account.models import Account

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.PointField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='locations', default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Location, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`Seializer.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_gis.serializers import GeoFeatureModelSerializer
from location.models import Location

class LocationSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        geo_field = 'location'
        auto_bbox = True
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'name', 'location', 'address', 'created', 'owner']

    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
```

`views.py`

```
class LocationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Location.objects.all()

    serializer_class = LocationSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
    bbox_filter_field = 'location'
    bbox_filter_include_overlapping = True
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter,
                       InBBoxFilter, TMSTileFilter, DistanceToPointFilter]
    pagination_class = GeoJsonPagination
    search_fields = ['=name', 'owner']
    ordering_fields = ['name', 'owner']
    ordering = ['created']

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just take out jquery django admin solution and put it as REST. I made a boilerplate with DRF, geodjango and leaflet. Check it out [here](https://hvitis.dev/geolocation-tutorial-geodjango-demo-and-gis-postgis-data-to-build-app-using-rest-api). Maybe it will help.